# Unexpected result with subtraction in aggregate function

Tags: mysql

Why do i get different sums

```
SELECT SUM(`amount` - `paid_amount`), SUM(`amount`) - sum(`paid_amount`) FROM `invoice`
```

In both cases i expect to get equal amounts but i don't

Comment: Addition and subtraction are commutative operations, so in fact the two sums should be the same.  Can you include sample data?  Maybe the issue here is just rounding error.

Comment: Example data and table ddl showing the problem would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sum will only include rows where amount and paid_amount are not null, because `-` returns null if either operand is null and `sum` returns the sum of all non-null values.

If there are no null values involved and you are seeing a slight difference between the two, you likely are using float or double type columns instead of decimal types.  Try casting to a decimal type inside the sum.

Comment: as it turns out the reason was null values in paid_amount

Comment: @tsanchev if this answer solved your problem, can you upvote it (click on the up arrow a the top left of the answer)?